# getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() returning -1 : OpenCV [cuda] built with vcpkg

Tags: opencv, cuda, vcpkg

Building an OpenCV CUDA app on win10 with MSVC 2017 using the opencv[cuda] package installed by vcpkg. To check for usable devices, I call getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() and it returns -1, which OCV documents as meaning cuda support is enabled but the CUDA driver is incompatible.
Re-installing opencv[cuda] with vcpkg did not help.
Can you suggest a way to diagnose or fix?

Comment: verify that you have a proper CUDA config. follow the windows install guide provided by NVIDIA, including the verification steps.  I would generally suggest having the latest driver for your GPU installed, for maximum compatibility.  You may also need to make sure you have the proper CUDA version selected to match whatever your OCV was built against.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  The machine is an old gaming laptop whose most recent recommended nVidia display driver is 425.31.  I had recently installed CUDA toolkit 10.2, whose runtime is actually incompatible with that driver.  Rolling back to toolkit 10.1 resolved the problem.